# Translating python RSA and Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5 code to java/kotlin

Tags: python, java, kotlin, encryption, rsa

I have some small python code that I want to translate into the equivalent Java/Kotlin code.  The python code gets a key off a JSON and encodes it to utf-8 standard. It then base64 decodes it and seems to import an RSA key. I am unsure what the cipher part is doing. However it then encrypts the email, password, and phone with the cipher, and then base64 encodes it. I have attempted to do it myself but get lost at the point of the cipher.

Python

```py
jsonValue = resp.json()["Content"]["pkey"].encode()
pkeyBase64 = base64.b64decode(jsonValue).decode()
pkey = RSA.importKey(pkeyBase64)
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(pkey)

email = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(email.encode())).decode()
phone = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(phone.encode())).decode()
password = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(password.encode())).decode()
```

Attempt In Kotlin

```kt
val base64Decoder = Base64.getDecoder()
val base64Encoder = Base64.getEncoder()
val base64EncodedPkey = body["Content"]?.jsonObject?.get("pkey")?.toString()
val base64DecodedPkey = base64Decoder.decode(base64EncodedPkey)
val pkey = getPrivateKey(String(base64DecodedPkey)) ?: return
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")

private fun getPrivateKey(base64PrivateKey: String): PrivateKey? {
    var privateKey: PrivateKey? = null
    val keySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64PrivateKey.toByteArray()))
    var keyFactory: KeyFactory? = null
    try {
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    try {
        privateKey = keyFactory?.generatePrivate(keySpec)
    } catch (e: InvalidKeySpecException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return privateKey
}
```

Comment: Does your `pkey` get a correct value? Where are you stuck? After you create a cipher you init it and then feed it ciphertext as bytes.... Java defaults to PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption / decryptin, but I'd specify `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` explicitly (never mind the ECB in there, it's meaningless).

Comment: If everything else looks correct, then I am stuck on how to initialize the cipher with the privatekey, and the proper way to encode a string with it @MaartenBodewes

Comment: Can you post an example for `jsonValue`? Porting also depends on the format and encoding of the key. The Python code doesn't allow much inference, as `importKey()` supports almost all format and encodings. And `base64.b64decode(jsonValue).decode()` only makes sense if `jsonValue` is a first (e.g. ASCII) encoded and then Base64 encoded PEM key, but that would be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Also, in the Python code, encryption is performed, which indicates a public key and not a private key.

Comment: @Topaco Unfortunately I cannot post an example json, however by the time ti gets to the RSA key it be utf8 encoded. I know how to encode a String to utf8 though, so I don't need an example of that part. Thanks for the info about PublicKey, a code example would be super helpful 

Comment: Depends on the format of the key. If it is an X.509/SPKI key, try `X509EncodedKeySpec`. This requires a DER encoded key.

Comment: @Topaco based on the code it seems to be RSA

Comment: RSA public keys can have different formats (X.509 or PKCS#1) and encodings (PEM or DER). Both cannot be derived so easily from the Python code, because `importKey()` supports most formats and encodings. Not so Java/Kotlin, here the implementation depends on format and encoding of the key.

Comment: @Topaco makes sense. I can figure that out, however I can still accept an answer that shows how to do it with `X509EncodedKeySpec`. As All I would have to change once I figure out what spec it is is that one part.